# jQuery AJAX make command render 404 results

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have the following jQuery

**JS:**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    async:false,
    data: {}
})
.done(function( msg ) {
    console.log(msg);
}).fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
    alert('Could not find file!'+textStatus);
});
```

If a page exists it will retrieve the **contents of the html of the page into the variable 'msg'**.

If it doesn't exist however... I have a custom 404 response that I want to send to users if they attempt to retrieve the files through AJAX to request a page.  My problem is the .fail response only gives me jqXHR and textStatus but no msg, so I can't show the contents of my 404 page!

**If the jQuery AJAX returns an error (for example 404 not found) how can I get it to print the results from the server?**

I've looked around on jQuery's documentation and could not find anything, any help is appreciated!

Comment: Try `jqXHR.responseText`?

Comment: you know what I think you are right, I was not aware that was inside the jqXHR object!

Comment: Make that the official answer so I can give you credit :), cause it worked for me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument `jqXHR` is a jQuery object that extends the native `XMLHttpRequest` object.

Documentation here: [jqXHR](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR)

Since it's essentially an XHR object, you should be able to find the response (if it exists) in the property `responseText` of that object.

```
jqXHR.responseText
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks for this and showing the documentation.  It was really hidden as a minor detail in there.

Answer (score 1):

Following  nderscore

html

```
<p id="results"></p>
```

js

```
var request = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    // url: url,
    async:false,
    data: {}
});
request.done(function( msg, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
        if (jqxhr.status === 200) {
            $("#results").html("status: "+ jqxhr.status+"<br\/><br\/>"+JSON.stringify(msg) );
   };
    console.log(msg, jqxhr.status === 200);
})
request.fail(function( msg, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
    if (jqxhr.status === 404) {
    $("#results").html('Could not find file!'+textStatus);
   };
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/ADF2f/